Disable Yum Module in Puppet
I am using Puppet server 6.7 on CentOS release 6.10, I need to upgrade it but not today. I don't know if it's my puppet version or my code.
I maintain a local offline repository for PostgreSQL pkgs, etc, because the RHEL provided pkgs are incomplete and the wrong version. RHEL 8 provides postgresql in what they call a "module" and as such my pkgs are, to use their term, 'filtered out' , so that I cannot see/install them. They say they are not available.
# yum repoinfo add-ons_rhel-8
...
Repo-pkgs : 13
Repo-available-pkgs: 6
...
Total packages: 13

I can get access and install my pkgs if I disable the Postgresql module manually.
# yum module disable postgresql

What I would like to know is how to disable the postgresql module via Puppet? I've tried a couple things to no avail.
For example:
package { 'postgresql':
ensure => '10',
provider => 'dnfmodule',
enable_only => false
}


I found the answer there https://serverfault.com/questions/1090410/dnf-enable-disable-in-puppet?newreg=55f6330b99b54e86b5e302f59cf9e32d dnfmodule works as a charm
